# Notepad++ - Selecting or Highlighting multiple sections of repeated text IN 1 LINE

Tags: regex, notepad++, soundcloud

I have a text file in Notepad++ that contains about 66,000 words all in 1 line, and it is a set of 200 "lines" of output that are all unique and placed in 1 line in the basic JSON form `{output:[{output1},{output2},...}]}`.

There is a set of characters matching the RegEx expression `"id":.........,"kind":"track"` that occurs about 285 times in total, and I am trying to either single them out, or copy all of them at once.

Basically, without some super complicated RegEx terms, I am stuck because I can't figure out how to highlight all of them at once, and also the Remove Unbookmarked Lines feature does not apply because this is all in one line. I have only managed to be able to Mark every single occurrence.

So does this require a large number of steps to get the file into multiple lines and work from there, or is there something else I am missing?

Edit: I have come up with a set of Macro schemes that make the process of doing this manually work much faster. It's another alternative but still takes a few steps and quite some time.

Edit 2: I intended there to be an answer for actually just highlighting the different sections all at once, but I guess that it not possible. The answer here turns out to be more useful in my case, allowing me to have a list of IDs without everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to already have a regex which matches single instances of your pattern, so assuming it works and that we must use Notepad++ for this:

Replace `.*?("id":.........,"kind":"track").*?(?="id".........,"kind":"track"|$)` with `\1`.

If this textfile is valid JSON, this opens you up to other, non-notepad++ options, like using Python with the json module.

*Edited to remove unnecessary steps*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually didn't notice that someone answered until my post was approved today (lol). In the meantime, I used macroing to nail it down into lines and erase what I didn't need These files are indeed in JSON format but do not have that file extension, and I am not that fluent in python. Also, in my case, it is more useful to replace with `\1\n` than just `\1` so that I don't still have just one line of text.